# MongoDB query in Spring repository: limit number of records after filter

Tags: spring, mongodb

I have the following query (with hard-coded parameters for simplicity) , using the "@Query" annotation within a Spring repository:

@Query("{$query : {status:'Failed'}, $maxScan: 10}")

The intent of this query is to read the first 10 records from the database that have a status of "Failed" (the records are system jobs).  However, the query will first read 10 records, then read records with a status of "Failed" from those 10 records.

I need to apply the limit to a resultset after the filter is applied, not before.  How can I modify the above query to return the first 10 records of the resultset that is read after the filter logic is applied, i.e. the first 10 records with a status of "Failed"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is resolved.  Pageable solves the issue.  Not sure why I was getting errors before, but now it works.  Thanks ku*.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When using Spring Data MongoDB, I think generally you'll want to use the `Pageable` interface for these queries. Example:

```
@Query("{status: 'Failed'}")
List<Record> findFailedRecords(Pageable pageable);

// or even better without the @Query annotation just:

List<Record> findByStatus(String status, Pageable pageable);
```

Then, to call:

```
yourRecordRepo.findFailedRecords(new PageRequest(0, 10));

// or using the other method:

yourRecordRepo.findByStatus("Failed", new PageRequest(0, 10));
```

That will fetch the first page of 10 failed Records.

Comment: I had tried Pageable, but it gives errors when using Query annotation in Spring repository.  My query is complicated so needs Query, I posted a trivial query so that we have a clear example.  I need to be able to resolve this issue with the Query annotation, any help is appreciated!

Comment: How can I get last N records ?

Comment: Hi, this works... but how will I know how many pages are there? or is there an easy way to know the total number of records/results so that I can compute the number of pages... then I can loop to each page using PageRequest?

Comment: btw, I am using json query and pageable... but I have no idea how I can get the result count from json query

Comment: new PageRequest(0,10); is deprecated. Use PageRequest.of(0, 10) instead

Answer (score -5):

`$limit` is what you need.

Limit - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/#cursor.limit

```
mongos> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "status" : "Failed" }
{ "_id" : 2, "status" : "Pass" }
{ "_id" : 3, "status" : "Failed" }
{ "_id" : 4, "status" : "Pass" }
{ "_id" : 5, "status" : "Failed" }
{ "_id" : 6, "status" : "Pass" }
{ "_id" : 7, "status" : "Failed" }
{ "_id" : 8, "status" : "Pass" }
{ "_id" : 9, "status" : "Failed" }
{ "_id" : 10, "status" : "Pass" }
mongos> db.test.find({status: "Failed"})
{ "_id" : 1, "status" : "Failed" }
{ "_id" : 3, "status" : "Failed" }
{ "_id" : 5, "status" : "Failed" }
{ "_id" : 7, "status" : "Failed" }
{ "_id" : 9, "status" : "Failed" }
mongos> db.test.find({status: "Failed"}).limit(3)
{ "_id" : 1, "status" : "Failed" }
{ "_id" : 3, "status" : "Failed" }
{ "_id" : 5, "status" : "Failed" }
```

Comment: I tried "$limit", but it did not work.  This is the syntax I used, but this gets all records from the database (with status of "Failed"):  @Query("{$query : {status:'Failed'}, $limit: 10}").  Is this syntax correct?

Comment: @user2984914 updated the answer with a sample test data using limit

Comment: @AjayGeorge, How does this translate to into Java code (when using Spring).  That is what the question.