# Spring java MongoDB @Query annotation for order top or first records

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I use `@Query` annotation and crudRepository to fetch data from MongoDB. 
Example:

```
@Query("{$query: id: ?0}, $orderby: {dateTime: -1}}")
public List<A> findId(
    Integer id, Pageable pageable
);
```

What do I need to add to my `@Query` notation if i want to fetch only first N records of collection, or only top N records of collection? I would like to use dynamic query and dynamic set limit and order (first or top records).

Comment: Look at the [**documentation**](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB query in Spring repository: limit number of records after filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939462/mongodb-query-in-spring-repository-limit-number-of-records-after-filter)

Comment: My problem is not duplicate it. I want to get via @Query annotation something like that: SELECT TOP 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can append your `@Query` with **$limit : 10**, or rename your method like : find `First10ByDateDesc()`

Comment: In this case i fetch first 10 records. What need to append, if i want to fetch top 10 records?

Comment: Actually It's not the right answer since you are not using the aggregation framework, but you can infer your query by renaming your method : a method named **findFirst10OrderByDateTimeDesc** should work fine.

Comment: In this case i can't dynamically change limit for records

Comment: This wasn't your request!
Check this : http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result

Answer (score 0):

Use the variable sort of the `@Query`:

```
@Query(value = "{}", sort = "{ _id : -1 }")
```

As an example for `"order by id desc"`.