# Unknown top level operator: $limit

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

Throws an error:

Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'unknown top level operator: $limit'

```
@Query("{ 'userID' : ?0, $limit : 5, $orderby : { 'startTime' : -1 } }")
```

How could this be written in terms of @Query annotation?

Comment: Not user if there is @Query equivalent but you can try repository methods. Something like `Pojo findTop5ByUserIDOrderByStartTimeDesc(String userID)` should work.

Comment: I want to be able to have a variable limit parameter as ?1.

Comment: okay. try `Pageable`. Something like in repository `findByUserIDOrderByStartTimeDesc(String userID, Pageable page)` and you can call `findByUserIDOrderByStartTimeDesc("123", new PageRequest(0,5))`

Comment: Thanks! I did this findByUserIDOrderByStartTimeDesc("123", PageRequest.of(0, limit)) since new PageRequest has been deprecated. The limit works fine 

But it OrderBy doesn't work!

Comment: You are welcome. This should have worked. `PageRequest` also supports sort. You can try sending sort criteria in page request and see.

Comment: Yes, `findReservationsByUserID(userID,
                PageRequest.of(0, limit, Direction.DESC, "startTime"))` this worked for me. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think it is possible to include sort and limit in the `@Query` annotation but you can use query methods.

Use `Pageable` with Sort Option.

Something like

```
findByUserID(userID, PageRequest.of(0, limit, Direction.DESC, "startTime"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```java
@Query("{'userID' : ?0}, $limit : 1, $orderby : {'startTime' : -1 }")
```

as these guys do: 
[Spring java MongoDB @Query annotation for order top or first records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33781643/spring-java-mongodb-query-annotation-for-order-top-or-first-records/33781921)

Note: no need in outer-most curly braces, they are added implicitly. Instead, wrap your `userID` condition into curly braces.